# golang how to concatenate []byte key vaules with other variable

Tags: go

How to concatenate variable value into the byte key values ?

```
type Result struct {
        SummaryID       int              `json:"summaryid"`
        Description     string           `json:"description"` 
    }

byt := []byte(`
                        {
                            "fields": {                                                              
                               "project":
                               { 
                                  "key": "DC"
                               },
                               "summary": "Test" + Result.SummaryID,    
                               "description": Result.Description,
                               "issuetype": {
                                  "name": "Bug"
                               }
                           }
                        }`)
```

Note: values of `Result.SummaryID` and `Result.Description` return from the `db.Query()` and `rows.Scan()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go doesn't support string interpolation, so you'll have to use something like [`fmt.Sprintf`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sprintf) or the [`template`](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/) package if you want to compose strings out of smaller substrings.

You can do the former like so:

```
var buf bytes.Buffer
byt := []byte(fmt.Sprintf(`
                    {
                        "fields": {
                          "project":
                           { 
                              "key": "DC"
                           },
                           "summary": "Test%d",
                           "description": "%s",
                           "issuetype": {
                              "name": "Bug"
                           }
                       }
                    }`, result.SummaryID, result.Description))
```

Though I would really advise against it, since the [`encoding/json`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/) package is designed for safely and sanely outputting JSON strings.

[Here's an example](https://play.golang.org/p/oAUaiRyt_5) that uses struct embedding for the main object, and maps elsewhere to demonstrate both approaches.

```
type WrappedResult struct {
    Project map[string]string `json:"project"`
    Result
    IssueType map[string]string `json:"issuetype"`
}

byt, err := json.MarshalIndent(map[string]interface{}{
    "fields": WrappedResult{
        Result: result,
        Project: map[string]string{ "key": "DC" },
        IssueType: map[string]string{ "name": "Bug" },
     },
});
```

(note that your type declaration contradicts your JSON example in that the former specifies `summaryid` but the latter has `summary`)

Comment: Awesome ! Superb solution at one short. Love You! Keep up with great work.